# iOS - Broadcast SMS (Send SMS to multiple recipients, not as a group MMS?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm working on an app with this requirement:

- Send SMS to multiple recipients
- Recipients can't see each other

It seems that the MFMessageComposeViewController only does a group MMS. I haven't seen anyone asking this question, so maybe I'm just not looking somewhere obvious. Is what I'm trying to do possible on iOS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SMS doesn't have the concept of groups.  The receiver does not see or know about other receivers in any way.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I do this?

Comment: Just set the `recipients` property of the controller.  It takes an array of phone numbers (as strings).

Comment: As I said in the question, this creates a group message where the recipients see each other, so this is not a solution.